# Always mute all sound from all tabs in an Android browser (Preferably FireFox)

Tags: gratis, android, audio, web-browser, firefox

I don't ever want to hear any sounds from my Android web browser - ever, under any circumstances.

I currently use FireFox and would accept an add-in for that. I would equally be willing to use any other browser which has "mute all" baked into the browser, without the need for an add-on.

Comment: Not as specific as you're asking for, and it's commercial or adware rather than gratis, but there's [this](https://fieldguide.gizmodo.com/set-different-volume-levels-for-each-app-on-your-androi-1756332280), which seems to provide a superset of the functionality you're looking for, in that it can mute arbitrary apps. Maybe other visitors to this question will find it useful, even though it doesn't meet all your requirements.

Comment: I think that I can stretch to the $0.99 premium  version ;-) Since no one else seems to be answering, feel free to post that as an answer (+1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a tool called [App Volume Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spycorp.appvolumecontrol), which sets the volume level for any of your apps, not just your browser. It's "free" in ad-supported form, or you can get a [paid version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spycorp.appvolumecontrolpro).

References:

- [Set Different Volume Levels For Each App on Your Android Smartphone](https://fieldguide.gizmodo.com/set-different-volume-levels-for-each-app-on-your-androi-1756332280)
- [Volume Control Tweaks for Android That You Need to Use](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/volume-control-tweaks-android-you-need-use/)

Comment: My apologies for taking so long to accept this as the answer.  It seems to e working just fine with FireFox. Tested it with YouTube & didn't hear a peep , even at full volume - while other apps still have sound.

Comment: Hey, no worries. Better to wait a while to ensure that it really works, and to give other people a chance to offer an even better answer, than to jump the gun, in my opinion. It's not like I was waiting on the edge of my seat for those 15 rep points to unlock some urgently needed privilege. ;)

Comment: In fact, I liked it so much that I paid for it. It certainly saved me the effort of coding my own.