# Private Android browser which can mute and, preferably, strip ads & videos

Tags: gratis, android, web-browser

The accepted solution to my previous question, [Always mute all sound from all tabs in an Android browser (Preferably FireFox)](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/49593/always-mute-all-sound-from-all-tabs-in-an-android-browser-preferably-firefox) no longer works.

I will, of course, contact the author of [App Volume Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spycorp.appvolumecontrol) which I purchased and which has been working perfectly until a recent factory refresh & reinstall.

In the meantime, I have never, and will never, under any circumstances listened to audio or watched a video in a browser on my Android 'phone.

And I am mightily pissed off by auto-play videos on otherwise reputable news sites, which generally auto-play at highly inconvenient moments.

Is there a gratis Android browser which never plays audio, or which offers a mute option which works 100% ?

Beyond that, it would be nice to have a browser which strips ads and videos and never even displays them.

The more secure/tracker proof, the better.

Comment: To filter ads I use brave but I don't think anything works *always* in blocking both ads and autoplay because the bad marketing guys will always find new ways to trigger unwanted events on our clients. It's an ongoing battle..

Comment: I would be happy just to stop "reputable" news sites auto-playing video or be able to mute the entire browser; everything else would just be a bonus